# Why is the hashcombine function in .net Framework internal?

Tags: c#, .net, hash, frameworks

Maybe someone can explain me why the hashcode-combine functions are internal at .net framework?

- [HashCodeCombiner](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Util/HashCodeCombiner.cs,21fb74ad8bb43f6b)
- [array](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,87d117c8cc772cca)

It is a very common function and the task of a framework is to offer common functions or not? Obviously it is already there redundant.

Comment: If they made it public then there's a serious risk that .NET programmers will use it everywhere.  It most certainly is not the kind of hash combiner that is *suitable* to be used everywhere, it is very expensive.  Okay in a web app, not when it generates the key of a Dictionary in a desktop app for example.

Comment: Thx for your answer, i was asking because i need this function several times and found a lot of question about the implementation at stackoverflow. So I was interested in the architecture decision.